# GradientDrawable with 3 colors, how to adjust size of middle color

Tags: android, drawable, gradient

I am working on a project that uses a *GradientDrawable* to create a gradient. The user picks two colors and the app creates a gradient with them. I also need to allow the user to adjust the level of gradient. I used the *setLevel()* function to adjust this and it is working great when I have two colors.

The problem is when you create a *GradientDrawable* with an array of colors that has 3 (or more) colors. Then when you use '*setLevel()*' you actually just move the middle color up or down on the image.

What I intend to do is allow the user to adjust the amount of the middle color. If the user chose black and white, for example, and chose to have very little white, the image would have a white line across the middle that had a gradient into the black on both sides (top and bottom). As the user adjusts the gradient level, the white line would spread out more, but very gradually, not just making a larger bright white line across the middle.

I am starting to think that using a *GradientDrawable* with 3 colors is NOT the way to go. I image the proper solution has to do with creating some kind overlay or layered drawable and adjust the middle color outwards...any ideas to get me pointed in the right direction?

Here is what I use currently (that doesn't work) to create the *GradientDrawable*:

```
new GradientDrawable(myOrientation, arrayOfColorsInt);
```

Looks like I cannot post any images (which would be very helpful) because I don't have the reputation....If there is any way I could send pictures to anyone as an example i can do that.

HERE IS what I ended up using based off the answer I accepted:

public static Drawable getLinearGradient(final int color1, final int color2, final int height) {
    ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
            LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height,
                new int[] { 
                    color1,
                    color1, 
                    color2,
                    color1,
                    color1}, //substitute the correct colors for these
                new float[] {
                    0, .25f, 0.50f, .75f, 1 },
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
             return lg;
        }
    };
    PaintDrawable p = new PaintDrawable();
    p.setShape(new RectShape());
    p.setShaderFactory(sf);
    return (Drawable)p;

Comment: you can post the links to the pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach. I haven't done this in a while, and this is from memory, so you might have to experiment a bit. To draw your Drawable, use a Paint object that uses a LinearGradient as its shader (instead of a solid color). Give the LinearGradient an array of five int colors.

`{top color, top color, center color, bottom color, bottom color}`

A LinearGradient also has an array of floats for normalized positions of the colors in the gradient, so you can control the positions of the second and fourth elements to get the effect you want.

Since a float array is an object, you can just keep a reference to this array and modify it's [1] and [4] elements and invalidate your view when the user changes the level.

Your Drawable doesn't need to be a GradientDrawable for you to use this Paint object.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that briefly last night before posting the question. However, that didn't seem to create a smooth gradient. If I wanted more middle color I created an array of like 8 elements, then set multiple elements to the middle color (like elements 3&4). However, that seemed to just make a wide band across the middle instead of the just increasing the gradual gradient space across the top/bottom colors.

Comment: You might need to link to a picture to describe what you want it to look like.

Comment: So the first image is what it would look like if the user chooses very little gradient of the middle color. The second link is what the image should look like if the user chooses more of the middle color.  With the linear gradient it seemed like the middle color just exapanded a large band of white, rather than spreading out the white out further into the black like the links show.

Comment: Did you try it with exactly five elements with the colors set as I described? I would expect that to get exactly the results you show in your pictures. You just need to change the values of the second and fourth elements of the positions float array. From your first comment above it sounds like you were over-complicating it and maybe left the positions float array as null.

Comment: You're right, I over complicated things and your solution seems to be working exactly as expected. I just adjust the 2nd and 4th float values to adjust my gradient...  Thanks!